# AJAX and PHP - Check until variable equals yes

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I basically want to check something every 10 seconds until variable equals yes.

shared.php

```
if ($sharecount > 0) {
$shared = "yes";
}

else {
$shared = "no";
}
```

Now this:

```
<script>
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: 'shared.php',
    success: function(data){
        document.write(data);
    }
});
</script>
```

just returns yes or no. How can I get it to keep checking until yes? If the php returns no, show message and check again in 10 seconds. if yes, show a different message and stop checking.

Comment: Probably https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setInterval

Comment: @user3783243 The problem with using `setInterval` is that you can't know exactly when the ajax call will complete so it could be possible to have one that returns `'no'` complete after one that returns `'yes'`, so the call has to be recusrive.

Comment: @ExplosionPills Ah, that makes sense. There isn't another way to do it on a timed interval though, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a function that does the ajax call and call it again on failure.

```
function callShared() {
  $.get('shared.php', data => {
    if ('yes' === data) {
      document.write(data);
    } else {
      callShared();
    }
  });
}

// initial call of the function.
callShared();
```

You probably don't want to use `document.write` and do some kind of DOM manipulation instead.

Comment: Possibly should make the recursive call `setTimeout(callShared, 10000)` so it doesn't continually check?

Comment: Thanks! Exactly what I needed.

Comment: @OneZeroOne consider upcoming and accepting answers that help you

Comment: @Nick yes, you could do that too